# Style guide for questions and answers

Tags: discussion, answer-format, faq-suggestion

Following the style guides on [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style), I would like to propose that we create a style guide of our own.  Let's hold ourselves to a high standard and create or promote questions and responses that can be understood and followed by people who have just started with Ubuntu.  Let's make this a hallmark of the Ubuntu Stack Exchange over other resources.

In what ways do people overcomplicate responses to questions?  What can they do to ensure that their responses are understood by all audiences, not just the most technical among us?

What would a badly formatted question or answer look like compared to a well formatted variant?

Should we avoid simply forwarding people to [wiki](http://wiki.ubuntu.com) and [help](http://help.ubuntu.com) pages, and provide a response tailored to their individual question?  Or is there a way that an external resource can be incorporated into a response without completely deferring responsibility to it?

Answer (score 62):

It appears that most of the questions will be of the form "How do I do [some action]?" I think the perfect answer to one of these questions would be a [brief walkthrough](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-to-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu/794#794) of the steps required to complete the action.

If the question is something new users might have to deal with, put the GUI answer first, ideally with a screenshot.

## Guidelines

- Break up your text, leave room to breathe.

  A wall of text can look tedious and some people just won't read it. Break up your text into small paragraphs of a few sentences. Point out where the important information is.
- For commands that users need to type into their terminal use backticks so that the site renders it in a `monospace font` so it's easier to distinguish what is a command and what is part of the surrounding text.
- [Don't use $'s](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/282/dollar-sign-in-command-line-instructions) for answers in the terminal (unless you're also showing output).
- If something is a series of steps, break it down into a numbered list so it's easier to read instead of one line.
- Don't **overformat** *your* questions **and** answers, *they* become ***hard to read***, `remember` that **less is more**, <strike>not more</strike>.
- Question titles should ideally be actual questions, beginning with a capital letter and ending with a question mark.

  - **Good example**:

    > How can I upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10?
  - **Bad example**:

    > upgrade ubuntu 12.10

  You should not force the title to be a question, but at least **try to write a meaningful title.**

### Images

- If an image is too large to fit on the page, instead of reminding the user that
  they can right click it and select show image, make it a link to a larger
  version of the same image. Don't use pre-formatted linking thumbnails with
  extraneous information in them.
- Images and screen shots should be on their own paragraph; Make sure the image
  referece in the Markdown has a blank like before and after it. If you annotate
  an image, you can use `<br>*Picture of a cat*` on the same line to stick the
  text right onto the image. Use this technique sparingly.
- Images [*should not*](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/176889) be used if the sole purpose of the image is to display text (terminal or otherwise). An image takes more bandwidth and is does not support screen reading software. Text should instead be copied into a [quote](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) or [code](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) block as appropriate.

### Links and References

- If your answer is behind a link, on someone's website or in a manual somewhere,
  rather than just linking to it, summarise the information in your answer. Make
  sure that your summary is a good representation of the linked content, since
  the link might not be reachable in the future.

  - **Good Example:**

    > The [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/Setup/Maverick) has a solution for your problem:
    >
    > - Go to the Ubuntu One Preferences ...
    >
    >   [...]
  - **Bad Example:**

    > Here's your solution: http://dead-link.example.net/

Also remember that blogs and news sites quickly go out of date, punting someone to an older blog means we can't improve it over time like we can an answer right on the site.

- **Give credit where credit's due**

  You are more than welcome to post an answer based on someone else's findings. Just
  give them the credit they deserve. Do not paraphrase someone else's text, but quote
  it directly.

  - Good Example:

    > It says that was "Suggested in xulrunner-1.9.1 in Ubuntu Karmic package "xulrunner-1.9.1"
    >   by ZhongHan Cai on 2009-09-21". There, it says that it was "Suggested in evince in
    >   Ubuntu Natty package "evince"  – *via [K. Deniz Ogut](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/Setup/Maverick)*
  - When you make any changes to a quote, mark them as such by putting the word or sentence in square brackets. If you emphasise specific parts of it, make your change apparent:

    > What [does] a badly formatted question or answer **look** like [...]?
    >    – *via [Evan](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers) (my emphasis)*

### Examples

#### Good formatting

1. Do step 1 (`command -1`)
2. Do step 2 (`command -2`)

#### Bad formatting

First, do step 1, then do step 2.

Comment: "[. . .] _punting_ someone to an older blog means we can't improve it over time like we can an answer right on the site." Did you mean _pointing_, or is there a pun here?

Comment: I am glad you still included a comprehensive discussion of responses using the command line rather than focus on just the GUI which is where I imagined this question and answers were headed after the OP mentioned "responses are understood by all audiences, not just the most technical among us". There remains a big role for the command line in Ubuntu and I regard that as a good thing, hence my +1.

Comment: How do you make buttons like ctrl + alt + T? I never found that in the styling guides.

Comment: What of titles? "Use the Capitalized Form" or "Use the sentence form"?

Comment: @James, you need to use <kbd> HTML tags for that