# Why do people prefix code examples with dollar sign?

Tags: discussion

I've been wondering about this for years, but never questioned it as far that I would ask this in public. I often come across websites that, for instance, explain the installation of a software in the command-line. What I don't get is why some keep the $-sign in their examples.

**Example:**

```
$ npm install -g some-package
$ gulp make
```

This, of course, makes it difficult to copy&paste the given example. Is this:

- pure laziness, where the author copies from this own shell?
- an intentional way to prevent copy & paste, because the author finds the read should understand what he does
- something else (explanation please)

Comment: I see that as "type this command at your shell prompt". And of course laziness, but in the positive sense: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LazinessImpatienceHubris

Comment: it is habit some sites don't have code formating, so you need to indicate it is in terminal - just edit it out we generally don't do that here for copy\paste ability (tripple click will include the $) http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/282/dollar-sign-in-command-line-instructions

Comment: If you have to execute a long list of commands prefixed with `$`: `sed 's/^$ //' <<EOF | bash`, paste the list of commands, hit ENTER, type EOF, hit ENTER. To edit it for the site: `sed 's/^$ //' <<EOF | xclip -sel clipboard`, paste the list of commands, hit ENTER, type EOF, hit ENTER.

Answer (score 10):

This is not a code example. The `$` at the beginning of the line indicates that it is a shell command. You can still copy and paste each line individually, as each line must be entered into the terminal individually anyway, and ignore the preceding `$` and  characters.

Examples which are actually shell scripts or other program code, do not start with the `$` symbol, and are generally preceded by a statement that the contents are in `foo.sh` file.

The `$` symbol is often used to denote hexadecimal values as well, when discussing lower level programming topics.

Comment: The $ sign also signify that the shell commands runs in normal user-mode, # denotes sudo or root rights needed for running the commands.
Merry Christmas

Answer (score 1):

The `$` at the beginning of a "typescript" is the simplified command prompt for an unprivileged user. For commands run in a `$UID==0` (aka `root`) environment, example writers use the `#` prompt. It's much simpler than prefixing each example command with "run this a user" or "run this as root".