# Should there be a question on AU or Meta about question/answer formatting?

Tags: discussion, answer-format

A link to a page where it shows pre tags and indents, code tags and backticks, and that type of thing.  There's already an AU question floating around about how to make answers more useful, but it might be time for one that addresses formatting.

I don't know that the proposed question belongs on AU since it's a question about AU, but either way.

Edit for clarification, I don't mean a this is how you do pre-tags/indents.  I mean something like "See how much better this looks with formatting"

It's something I think should be discussed.

Comment: We have one:

- http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is pretty good formatting help already if you click the question mark icon on the right of the editing tool bar.

It covers most of the editing questions I've ever had, but I'll admit that it took me a while to find it.  Perhaps having a label like "Editing help" next to the icon would make it more obvious to people?

Comment: I agree that the how to is there.  I more meant to make you question more useful, you might put command output in indents/pre's.  Let me see if I can clarify the question.

Comment: I think most people know that their command output listings or similar would look better preformatted.  In most cases, it seems that the new users either don't know how to do this or don't know it is possible.  So making the editing help more obvious might improve things.