# Can newbies get a feedback from senior community members?

Tags: discussion, community

I am somewhat new for askubuntu.com. Personally, as computing is one of my desired subject (but was not  lucky to learn), I am doing edit questions and try to answer from my little knowledge to improve my knowledge as well as to contribute this great social service done by Linux. How can we get a feedback from senior community members for improvements.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can always post on meta for feedback on what you're working on. I've been running into your edits recently and also just did a scan of some of your work. Overall, I think you're doing a great job helping people clear up their questions.

Three things I would work on:

- There's no need to add bold to most questions. Usually concentrating on making the question easier to understand with edits makes it easier to read rather than with bold.
- Try to fix the title as much as possible. This is very hard to do as you can probably figure out. The best edit you can make is one that makes everyone want to understand the question enough to click through to the actual question.
- You don't need to fix "thanks" and "please" parts of the question, just trim them out so that people reading can get right to the point!

Great job so far, thanks for contributing to Ubuntu!

Also if you haven't seen it yet, here's the style guide with a bunch of tips:

- [Style guide for questions and answers](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers)

Comment: Your feedback is so useful and encouraging

Comment: And some useful tips about edits.