# Formatting, backticks and editing

Tags: discussion, formatting

This was a concern [raised in UL some time ago](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1480/41104), but recently I've seen several cases where I've changed the use of backticks, I will ripoff strugee post from UL:

---

I've noticed that a lot of `new users` tend to `format` their `posts` like this, where they put things they want to `emphasize` or things that are even just barely vaguely `technical` in `code blocks`. **This drives me nuts.**

Is it OK to tell the person in a comment that they're formatting wrong, similar how we do the "welcome to Stack Exchange, we like repeatable questions" (or whatever other problem) dance?

---

(the bold part was added by *moí*)

Are not guiding correctly our users about the use cases of the backticks? As far I go, the backticks should be used to express some piece of "code" but not to emphasise words in the flow of the question, or I'm wrong?

Related:

- [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112)
- https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7437

Comment: Related: (MSO) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112, (Arqade Meta) http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7437 - The Arqade link in particular also details *why* this is bad practice, rather than just what to do about it.

Comment: The Arqade meta post was the first thing I thought of when I saw this

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are correct, the style guide mentions this too:

- [Style guide for questions and answers](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers)