# updating an answer based on some information from another answer to same post

Tags: discussion

I answered a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856967/is-there-an-installer-for-xubuntu-that-works-on-32bit-and-64bit-systems/856972#856972) and it was accepted then later refused. Now my problem is that a useful bit to the question was left out.

Now I see this bit in another answer, would it be wrong for me to:

- update my answer and add the bit I left out
- would this be considered stealing from another answer

I was tempted to add it but need more advice from more experienced members.

Comment: Tricky one... what specifically do you think your answer is missing that you would add to it?

Comment: The fact that a `32 bit installer` may be used only on `32 bit systems` and `64 bit installers` on both. I did not include this part. So yes an installer exists but the type of `system` will determine the type of installer used.

Comment: Is that true? Haha where does it say that?

Comment: mistake i meant. 32 bit on both and 64 bit on only 64 bit systems, hahahaha. Sorry about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this kind of thing needs to be decided on a case-by-case basis.

Of course, plagiarism is totally not OK and I think it's important to think carefully about how to be respectful and avoid treading on other users' toes.

In general, if I miss something from my answer and another answer includes it, I will upvote the other answer and either, leave the situation alone, or, especially if the information is really critical and cannot be left out, or there is another good reason to do so, add a *link* to the other answer in my own answer with something like "see answer by @AwesomePerson which explains such-and-such"

In this case, I have [edited your answer](https://askubuntu.com/posts/856972/revisions) as I think it made a valuable contribution but needed some clarification. I added the information you mentioned and upvoted both your post and sudodus'. I think that was an appropriate action in this case, but others may disagree with me.

Oh, and please [don't use backticks for emphasis](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7707/formatting-backticks-and-editing) ;)

Comment: Apparently it is acceptable here to convert a comment by another person to an answer. It's preferrable to ask them to do it, wait and then do it yourself if there's not timely response. I don't enjoy this, but it's what I was told.

Comment: @Zacharee1 yeah, that's another thing and I personally will make a CW there (or, if it makes sense, edit the information into someone else's post) unless I am able to write the answer from my own knowledge.  Speaking for myself, if I have an intention to answer the question then I genrally do so, and if my answer is in the comments, then I'd rather someone else made the efforts, so I think it's fine to do this, although I don't enjoy it either...