# Please don't approve edit-suggestions where code-format is used for emphasis

Tags: discussion

Today I saw a new user suggesting edits where he mainly used `code` for emphasis
e.g.

[pcname + mac filtered WIFI - not able to connect](https://askubuntu.com/q/988060/117103)

I edited one suggestion and rejected another but then saw that he has got approved suggestions with the same pattern.

Please help to educate new users to not fall into that trap.

Comment: You can link to the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) with: `[formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting)`

Comment: Or link to [editing-help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) with: `[editing-help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help)`

Comment: I've also noted that some users seems to use the quote for code (e.g. > versus four spaces).

Comment: I use code formatting a lot, without it commands can be hard to `find`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let's agree on some commonly accepted formatting guidelines](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15446/lets-agree-on-some-commonly-accepted-formatting-guidelines)

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for the catch and the rollback.
I've had words with those involved in the approval of the edit suggestion.

I think it's easy to get into a position where you assume people are trying to do good things and that the thought is what counts. This edit does sort of kind of highlight some important stuff... ish... But it's obviously a long way off our community standards. That's what counts.

Reviewing edits is something that always happens dead quick here and while I think most of the reviews are fine, I think some people miss out on how sacred they really are to us.

- It gives you —a battle-seasoned editing warlord— the perfect opportunity to make a post you might not have seen *even better*. Extra spacing, language edits, converting links out to be in the text, removing thanks, using code, block-code and block-quotes correctly... *You know* how things should look.
- Your re-edit (or decline-edit) shows the edit-suggester what we expected them to do. Their next edit might be better. Their next might be even better.
- We only have a finite amount of time before mediocre editors can edit without approval, and approve others' edits. That's why we need the bar so high here.

So if you don't have the time to give 120% to an edit suggestion, **just don't review edits today**. Let somebody with free time do it. There are other queues that are more black-and-white. Or hell, answer one of today's posts.