# Is there a style guide for these Ask Ubuntu lists?

Tags: discussion, style

I have looked at https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask .  A style guide shows what is wanted and how to incorporate various things.  For example, most professional journals and conference proceedings have a LaTeX, MS Word, CSS, etc., "template" to handle formatting (bold, underlined, italic, URLs, etc.)?  Are the instructions as to how to use the embedded on-line editor (that I am using to compose this question) to achieve the conforming formats?  An Ask Ubuntu moderator modified my posting,both in content (clarity for the intended audience) but also converted the format of certain parts of the posts ("commands", GUI use, etc.).  Although I appreciate such work, it is simpler to compose to the required style than post-posting edit.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Comment: @user.dz  Thank you.  Why does this guide not appear as a link when postings are discussed or even on the compose web entry to a question or comment?  Given this guide, has anyone written a template for LaTeX, MS Word, LibreOffice, or any of a number of HTML web page editors so that one can create the material off line and simple "copy and paste"?

Comment: @KGIII  How do I move this to meta?  Also, see the comment about making the document
askubuntu.com/editing-help – user.dz a link (URL) on the editing question, comment, and answer web interface on these lists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Style guide for questions and answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers) This seems to be what you're basically asking about, since you are already familiar with the editor from having posted 9 questions and 4 answers at Ask Ubuntu. If this is not what you intended, please comment and I'll refine my algorithm.

Comment: Also see [What is the preferred way to add a numbered list using markdown?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17926/)

Answer (score 4):

Well, it is all there. See when Asking a Question:

1. Quick Help as text below tool bar
2. Link to https://askubuntu.com/editing-help (same link I give in comment)
3. Help Center, search for *"format"* or *"MarkDown"* this is how it is called (An advanced alternative of the legacy [BBCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode)). Many editors in Ubuntu support it.

   [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting)
4. Link to Meta, If you find nothing and want to ask about site features and community.

[image: picture of help hint on ask a question]